# Understanding Boyer-Moore visually

Tags: algorithm, boyer-moore

I have researched the various solutions on StackOverflow already to try to understand how the Boyer-Moore algorithm functions, however I am looking more-so for a step-by-step illustration on how the algorithm actually functions (visual learning is much better for me).

I'm trying to understand this image, but I don't entirely understand why at comparison 6 it skips ahead:

[image: boyer-moore]

I'd prefer to see it drawn out better, but if you can tell me through pseudo code why this happens, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: [the wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string-search_algorithm#Description)

Comment: Because there is no `d` in the pattern. So the pattern will not match at any alignment which includes the `d` and thus it can be slid all the way over.

Comment: @rici I see, so if the string didn't have a `d` in it, then the string we're comparing to would handle it just like a bruteforce algorithm, just in reverse?

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing in Boyer Moore's algorithm is the *last occurrence table*, which is a preprocessing of the pattern. It stores the last index in which each distinct character in the pattern appeared.

The steps can be broken up as shown below, where I modified your visualization a bit.

[image: boyer-moore-diagramming]

**The shift steps are explained below**

1. Text character **a** mismatch with pattern character **b**.
   Character **a** appears in the last occurrence table with index 4.
   Shift pattern so index 4 aligns with the mismatched text character **a**.
2. Text character **a** mismatch with pattern character **c**.
   Character **a** appears in the last occurrence table with index 4.
   Shifting the pattern so index 4 aligns with the mismatched text character **a** would shift the pattern backward. This does not make sense, so all we can do is shift the pattern by 1.
3. Text character **a** mismatch with pattern character **b**.
   Character **a** appears in the last occurrence table with index 4.
   Shift pattern so index 4 aligns with the mismatched text character **a**.
4. Text character **d** mismatch with pattern character **b**.
   Character **d** does not appear in the last occurrence table.
   We can therefore shift the entire pattern past this mismatch.
5. Text character **a** mismatch with pattern character **b**.
   Character **a** appears in the last occurrence table with index 4.
   Shift pattern so index 4 aligns with the mismatched text character **a**.
6. All characters match, i.e. we have a full match. Shift the pattern naively by 1.
7. Same scenario as for comparison 7. Align pattern's index 4 with the mismatched text character **a**.
8. Same scenario as above.
9. Exact same scenario as for comparisons 2, 3, and 4. Shift pattern by 1.
10. Text character **b** mismatch with pattern character **a**. We reached
    the end of the text so we are done.